# Define the use of dates

Tags: dates

Can anyone tell me that whether I should write July 25 or July 25th if someone asks me when was I born? Should I answer "I was born on July 25" or "I was born on July 25th."?

Answer (score 3):

Since the "25(th)" refers to the *25th day of* July, you should say,

> "I was born on the 25th **of** July".

It is also common for people to say

> "I was born on July 25th".

Comment: Does this add anything extra to what I have written?

Comment: I believe so. Before you edited your answer, my first example was different to what you had suggested. My second example is also different from both answers you have provided. My apologies - I would have commented on your answer had I enough points to do so. @HimabinduBoddupalli

Comment: thank you for your answer HimabinduBoddupalli  @as4s4hetic

Comment: The question says ‘write’. This answer is about ‘say’.

Answer (score -1):

If you’re in America you can say ‘July 25’. But in the UK you need the ‘th’.

So it would be ‘I was born on July 25th’.

Actually, in speech, you’d add ‘the’, and sometimes ‘of’.

‘I was born on July *the* 25th’. Or, ‘I was born on *the* 25th *of* July’.

https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/how-to-say-the-date-in-english/

Comment: In Britain you would be more likely to say "I was born on (the) 25th (of) July". But there are numerous posts on this site concerning dates, and how they are written on each side of the pond - if anyone cares to look for them.